# Expected object or Value while read the .json file in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read the .json file in python.
Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_idf = pd.read_json('/home/lazzydevs/Data/datajs.json',lines = True)

print("Schema:\n\n",df_idf.dtypes)
print("Number of questions,columns=",df_idf.shape)
```

I checked my json file also it's also valid file.
Here is my .json file:

```
[{
  "id": "4821394",
  "title": "Serializing a private struct - Can it be done?",
  "body": "\u003cp\u003eI have a public class that contains a private struct. The struct contains properties (mostly string) that I want to serialize. When I attempt to serialize the struct and stream it to disk, using XmlSerializer, I get an error saying only public types can be serialized. I don't need, and don't want, this struct to be public. Is there a way I can serialize it and keep it private?\u003c/p\u003e",
  "answer_count": "1",
  "comment_count": "0",
  "creation_date": "2011-01-27 20:19:13.563 UTC",
  "last_activity_date": "2011-01-27 20:21:37.59 UTC",
  "last_editor_display_name": "",
  "owner_display_name": "",
  "owner_user_id": "163534",
  "post_type_id": "1",
  "score": "0",
  "tags": "c#|serialization|xml-serialization",
  "view_count": "296"
},{
  "id": "3367882",
  "title": "How do I prevent floated-right content from overlapping main content?",
  "body": "\u003cp\u003eI have the following HTML:\u003c/p\u003e\n\n\u003cpre\u003e\u003ccode\u003e\u0026lt;td class='a'\u0026gt;\n  \u0026lt;img src='/images/some_icon.png' alt='Some Icon' /\u0026gt;\n  \u0026lt;span\u0026gt;Some content that's waaaaaaaaay too long to fit in the allotted space, but which can get cut off.\u0026lt;/span\u0026gt;\n\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\n\u003c/code\u003e\u003c/pre\u003e\n\n\u003cp\u003eIt should display as follows:\u003c/p\u003e\n\n\u003cpre\u003e\u003ccode\u003e[Some content that's wa [ICON]]\n\u003c/code\u003e\u003c/pre\u003e\n\n\u003cp\u003eI have the following CSS:\u003c/p\u003e\n\n\u003cpre\u003e\u003ccode\u003etd.a span {\n  overflow: hidden;\n  white-space: nowrap;\n  z-index: 1;\n}\n\ntd.a img {\n  display: block;\n  float: right;\n  z-index: 2;\n}\n\u003c/code\u003e\u003c/pre\u003e\n\n\u003cp\u003eWhen I resize the browser to cut off the text, it cuts off at the edge of the \u003ccode\u003e\u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u003c/code\u003e rather than before the \u003ccode\u003e\u0026lt;img\u0026gt;\u003c/code\u003e, which leaves the \u003ccode\u003e\u0026lt;img\u0026gt;\u003c/code\u003e overlapping the \u003ccode\u003e\u0026lt;span\u0026gt;\u003c/code\u003e content. I've tried various \u003ccode\u003epadding\u003c/code\u003e and \u003ccode\u003emargin\u003c/code\u003es, but nothing seemed to work. Is this possible?\u003c/p\u003e\n\n\u003cp\u003eNB: It's \u003cem\u003every\u003c/em\u003e difficult to add a \u003ccode\u003e\u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u003c/code\u003e that just contains the \u003ccode\u003e\u0026lt;img\u0026gt;\u003c/code\u003e here. If it were easy, I'd just do that :)\u003c/p\u003e",
  "accepted_answer_id": "3367943",
  "answer_count": "2",
  "comment_count": "2",
  "creation_date": "2010-07-30 00:01:50.9 UTC",
  "favorite_count": "0",
  "last_activity_date": "2012-05-10 14:16:05.143 UTC",
  "last_edit_date": "2012-05-10 14:16:05.143 UTC",
  "last_editor_display_name": "",
  "last_editor_user_id": "44390",
  "owner_display_name": "",
  "owner_user_id": "1190",
  "post_type_id": "1",
  "score": "2",
  "tags": "css|overflow|css-float|crop",
  "view_count": "4121"
}]
```

Now i am trying to read the json file in python but every time it's showing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lazzydevs/Desktop/tfstack.py", line 4, in <module>
    df_idf = pd.read_json('/home/lazzydevs/Data/datajs.json',lines = True)
  File "/home/lazzydevs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 592, in read_json
    result = json_reader.read()
  File "/home/lazzydevs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 715, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data.split("\n")))
  File "/home/lazzydevs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 739, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "/home/lazzydevs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 849, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "/home/lazzydevs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 1093, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

I checked so many posts but not working...i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @luigigi is there any way to read multiple dict?

Comment: @Vinay i checked in online sites where its showing its valid json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code seems to work on my machine.

```
import pandas as pd

df_idf = pd.read_json('/home/lazzydevs/Data/datajs.json') 
print("Schema:\n\n",df_idf.dtypes)
print("Number of questions,columns=",df_idf.shape)
```

Comment: yes, same. Probably the `,lines = True` was the issue